# An integral inequality related to the normal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Through numerical experiments, I conjecture 
$$I=\int_0^\infty \big(\big|1-e^{\sigma(-x_1+x)}\big|-(1-e^{-\sigma x_1})\big)e^{-\frac{(x_1+x)^2}2}dx>0,$$
$\forall x_1>0,\, \sigma>0$. Is this true?

Comment: The integral can be calculated in closed form using the error function erf, if that helps.

Comment: @GregMartin: Of course that is true. But the question is whether that helps to derive the inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inequality is false. Indeed, as was noted in comments by Greg Martin and you, $I$ can be expressed in terms of the error function. Specifically, we have 
$$I=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\sigma  x_1} \left(2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \left(\sigma -2
   x_1\right)} \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sigma -2 x_1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma 
   \left(\sigma -2 x_1\right)} \text{erf}\left(\frac{x_1-\sigma
   }{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2}
   x_1\right)-2 \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{2} x_1\right) e^{\sigma 
   x_1}+\text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{2} x_1\right)+e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma  \left(\sigma -2
   x_1\right)}\right). 
$$
Now we can see that $I=-0.07296807214284069917\ldots<0$ for $x_1=9/10=\sigma$.

Here is the corresponding Mathematica notebook:

[image]

Comment: OK. Thank you, Iosif. Did you use Mathematica to get the expression and find the counterexample?

Comment: @Hans : Yes. I have now also added the expression for the limit of $I$ as $x_1\to\infty$, which provides another way to see that $I$ can be $<0$.

Comment: Why did you delete the limit approach? I thought it was a more elegant approach.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo when inputting the integrand. However, after that mistake is corrected, the result is still that $I$ can be $<0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was actually pondering about the discrepancy between your previous result and mine from SageMath while trying to verify your previous result.